# Angular array of fruits. Put each fruit in it's own list

Tags: angular

Use case = put each fruit into the correct list.
What's the best way to do this?

I know I could filter the list into an array for each fruit and then create the lists. However, I was trying not to do that; so that when the fruits array gets updated, so does each list automatically. The below is clearly not correct...

```
 fruits = [
  {type: 'apple', id: '1'},
  {type: 'apple', id: '2'},
  {type: 'apple', id: '3'},
  {type: 'orange', id: '4'},
  {type: 'orange', id: '5'},
  {type: 'banana', id: '6'},
  {type: 'banana', id: '7'},
 ];

 <ng-container *ngFor="let fruit of fruits">
    <ul>
        <li *ngIf="fruit.type === 'apple'">{{ fruit.type }}</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li *ngIf="fruit.type === 'orange'">{{ fruit.type }}</li>
    </ul>

    <ul>
        <li *ngIf="fruit.type === 'banana'">{{ fruit.type }}</li>
    </ul>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I would use a `Map<string, string>` or a `Record<string, string>`. And compute the keys on change in an array. (the keyvalue pipe would also work but it's impure). `{'apple': [1,2,3], 'orange': [4,5], 'banana': [6,7]}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using rxjs you could put your data into a subject. Filter on it per specific fruit type you want and then in the template use the `async` pipe to get the values you want.

It would roughly look like this.

```js
const fruits$ = new Subject([{
    type: 'apple',
    id: '1'
  },
  {
    type: 'apple',
    id: '2'
  },
  {
    type: 'apple',
    id: '3'
  },
  {
    type: 'orange',
    id: '4'
  },
  {
    type: 'orange',
    id: '5'
  },
  {
    type: 'banana',
    id: '6'
  },
  {
    type: 'banana',
    id: '7'
  },
]);

const apples$ = fruits$.pipe(filter(fruit => fruit.type === "apple"));
const oranges$ = fruits$.pipe(filter(fruit => fruit.type === "orange"));
const bananas$ = fruits$.pipe(filter(fruit => fruit.type === "banana"));
```

```html
<ul *ngIf="(apples$ | async) as apples">
  <li *ngFor="let apple of apples">{{ apple.type }}</li>
</ul>

<ul *ngIf="(orange$ | async) as oranges">
  <li *ngFor="let orange of oranges">{{ orange.type }}</li>
</ul>

<ul *ngIf="(banana$ | async) as bananas">
  <li *ngFor="let banana of bananas">{{ banana.type }}</li>
</ul>
```

If you want to reuse some of your html you could even iterate of each of the observables. Honestly not 100% sure you can build an array in the `*ngFor`, but otherwise do that in the actual component.ts file

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let fruit$ of [apples$, bananas$, oranges$]">
  <ul *ngIf="(fruit$ | async) as fruitArray">
    <li *ngFor="let fruitItem of fruitArray">{{ fruitItem.type }}</li>
  </ul>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I thinks its a bit of an overkill to wrap it into a subject.

Comment: @enno.void why?  In this example whenever the fruits$ subject changes, all the other values get updated automatically.  This is pretty standard reactive programming in Angular. It can then be used with onPush change detection for better performance as well.

Answer (score 1):

I guess the easiest solution is to use a angular pipe:

```
<h2>Oranges</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let fruit of fruits | type:'orange'">
    <li>{{ fruit.id }}</li>
</ul>
<h2>bananas</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let fruit of fruits | type:'banana'">
    <li>{{ fruit.id }}</li>
</ul>
<h2>apples</h2>
<ul *ngFor="let fruit of fruits | type:'apple'">
    <li>{{ fruit.id }}</li>
</ul>
```

Full example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-84vofq

Comment: this is what i did too, but it's 3 loops. Guess there's no other way, yeah?

Answer (score -1):

```
    fruits = [
     'apple',
     'orange',
     'banana'
       ];

 fruits1 = [
  {type: 'apple', id: '1'},
  {type: 'apple', id: '2'},
  {type: 'apple', id: '3'},
  {type: 'orange', id: '4'},
  {type: 'orange', id: '5'},
  {type: 'banana', id: '6'},
  {type: 'banana', id: '7'},
 ];


<ng-container>
    <ul *ngFor="let a of fruits">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let fruit of fruits1">
            <li *ngIf="fruit.type === a">{{ fruit.type }}</li>
        </ng-container>
    </ul>
</ng-container>
```

I Hope It will Help you.